# Turning off single category of categorized symbology in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, table-of-contents

I am new to ArcGIS Desktop.

I have one layer with different types of sewer: for rain water only, for waste water only and both mixed.
Every type of sewer should have his own color: rain - blue, waste water - brown, mixed - violet.
So I created a categorized symbology with three categories based on the layers attribut "type".

Now my problem is the following: I want to see only one type of sewer in my map, for example the one for rain water.

How can I get this done?

There is only one checkbox for the whole layer, not for the single categories in the toc.

Prior to ArcGIS/ArcMap I used GeoMedia from Intergraph/Hexagon and now in addition QGIS. In both GIS programs I'm able to turn off single categories but I couldn't find such a function in ArcGIS/ArcMap.

The only solution I have at the moment is to set the symbology of the categories I don't want to see to width zero or to insert the layer three times with single symbology and use filters for the type.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [Definition Query](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/displaying-a-subset-of-features-in-a-layer.htm) to limit your symbology to one `Type` attribute.

For example: `Type = "rain"`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! There´s really no other, more efficient way to geht this result?